# How to add another show/hide toggler div?

Tags: javascript

I found this code at W3S:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_hide_show

And what I'm looking for is not to have 1 div but to have 3 different divs to show/hide.

I believe this part `var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');` must be changed to be able to have plenty of different divs to show/hide..

Could anyone please tell me what should be written instead to make it work the way I want?

Thanks!
Kind regards,
Cynthia

Comment: Why not try it yourself, and if it doesn't work, return here with a question?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName("DIV");`

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV");

      for(var i=0; i < x.length; i++)
      {
        if (x[i].style.display === 'none') {
            x[i].style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          x[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    
}
```

```css
.myDIV {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div class="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<div class="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<div class="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I don't think I explained it the correct way, I'm sorry. I'm not looking for having 3 divs. I'm looking for having 3 "try it" buttons with different information that is showing once you click on the button. 

E.g "Try it button 1" shows a pink box with a name
"Try it button 2" shows a blue box with a number
"Try it button 3" shows a yellow box with an image

All of these should have the functionality to show/hide and is not depending on the other buttons.

Comment: Hi again @Raj, I used this part 'var x = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV");' of your code and figured it out in the end, thanks a lot!